How to get error details logs in log analytics workspace for synapse analytics workspace to be used as a dataset in power bi
I am creating a report in power bi wherein I monitor the pipelines and activties and I need to get the Error Code of each failed Activties but it is not available in "SynapseIntegrationActivityRuns" logs.
To know if a pipeline fails in synapse workspace we can view its error message in monitoring section->pipeline runs->pipeline name->error column
So how can I get error details of Synapse analytics workspace (pipeline & activity fails error message) in log analytics workspace?
I haven't tried creating a diagnostic settings since I am not sure if that is the way.

Unfortunately, the SynapseIntegrationActivityRuns  logs do not include the error details or messages that are available same as ADFActivityRuns.
Column  Type    Description
ActivityIterationCount  int 
ActivityName    string  
ActivityRunId   string  
ActivityType    string  
Annotations string  
_BilledSize real    The record size in bytes
Category    string  
CorrelationId   string  
EffectiveIntegrationRuntime string  
End datetime    
Error   string  
ErrorCode   string
ErrorMessage    string  
EventMessage    string  
FailureType string  
Input   string  

However, it appears there are not any columns in the SynapseIntegrationActivityRuns table that allow you to directly retrieve error details.
As a workaround, you could log your pipeline runs, including error details, into a custom SQL table, and then bring that data into Power BI for analysis.
Azure data factory How to catch any error on any activity and log it into database?

So i need to add this to all my pipeline runs?
